# Extract pyomo results to a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, pyomo

Can anyone help me extract the values from pyomo model into an excel file?

For example for this Objective function. I want the values for the models to be extracted into an excel file but dont know how...

```
def lastdeckung(model, t):
    return model.eigenproduktion[t] + model.stromimport[t] == model.verbrauch[t]
model.lastdeckung = Constraint(model.n, rule = lastdeckung)
```

As far as I was able to read online im supposed to create a pandas dataframe and afterwards extract that with the `to_csv` function.

I was able to get one function into a dataframe with this:

```
values = [value(model.stromimport[key]) for key in model.stromimport]
```

But I dont know how to add more...

Comment: If you can access the variable and expression values (which is pretty straightforward), why don't you do a little research on python's `csv` module, which can easily write csv files.  AVOID `pandas` here.  unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably better:

```
results = pd.DataFrame()
for v in model.component_objects(Var,active=True):
    for index in v:
        results.at[index, v.name] = value(v[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is trying to do this but finding it very slow because of a long index, I found the following to be 10 times faster.

```
results = pd.DataFrame()
for v in model.component_objects(Var, active=True):
    results[v.name] = [value(v[i]) for i in v]
```